# Column visibility not working when exporting to Excel

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a column in my report that I want to hide based on an expression:

```vb
=IIF((ReportItems!Textbox16.Value ="USD" OR Parameters!BinderID.Value=10263 OR Parameters!BinderID.Value=10536 OR Parameters!BinderID.Value=10718 OR Parameters!BinderID.Value=10248 OR Parameters!BinderID.Value=10535 OR Parameters!BinderID.Value=10960),True,False)
```

When I run the report the hidden expression is working very well: the column is hidden. However, when I export to Excel the column reappears while it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

[This discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/1012a7dc-ad8a-431c-a138-54a173e31016/) would suggest it cannot be done, and would require a work around such as a separate report with only the columns wanted.

Comment: I will explaine exactly what i want maybe there is another way to do it: my report has PageBreak by currency, when i export to excel sheets are created and named by currency; i have a column for premium for the original currency and another one converted to USD; i want to hide the column converted to USD in USD worksheet since it the original currency in this case is in USD. note that i also have a column displaying the currency in the report. i also tried to use ReportItems!Currency.Value in the hidden expression but it didnt allow since it is aggregate function. Any Ideas?

Comment: Doesn't seem likely, no =( Best of luck, though.